# Difference between 8.04 LTS (Hardy Heron), 8.10 (Intrepid Ibex), 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope)

Tags: ubuntu

What are Differences between 8.04 LTS (Hardy Heron), 8.10 (Intrepid Ibex), 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope) ? Which one the best to use?

Answer (score 3):

It's versions. The number has to be read as (Y)Y.MM. You might want to wait until tomorrow when 10.04 (2010 April) hits. This will also be an [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS).

There is a new version each April (x.04) and October (x.10) and an LTS (Long Term Support) every two years.

LTS Versions have the advantage that you can upgrade from LTS to LTS (every two years) where non-LTS Versions have to be updated incrementally which means two times a year. You can still choose not to upgrade at all but I wouldn't recommend that.

The question would rather be *which* Ubuntu to install. If you have slower hardware you could think about [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/) which needs a bit less resources. There are [several flavours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Variants) which might be interesting in different cases.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the different flavours, didn't think of that in my answer.

Comment: The LTS releases key advantage is that you don't have to update as often for server use due to the extended support time. If you are running 8.04 you will still get security updates until 2013 so you don't have to update to 10.04 when it arrives, unless you have specific need to such as wanting particular updated packages. Though if you wait until the next LTS release (12.04) you will need to upgrade twice (8.04->10.04 then 10.04->12.04).

Answer (score 1):

There are differences, including (and most noticeable for me)  different software included as default, at different versions.
Did you mean to not include the latest (9.10) in your options because one major difference is that from 9.10 and above, the [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) client is included by default.

As of later today, you will be able to download the very latest version, Ubuntu 10.04LTS (Lucid Lynx) will be available.

Personally I would always recommend either the latest standard release, or the latest long term support release (if you want the same operating system for a long time).
I would definitely recommend not using 8.10 because support for that version is due to stop now.

Answer (score 0):

The latest is usually the best to use, and then dist-upgrade to the next when it is time to do so.

> *-"Which one the best to use?"*

It depends on what your needs are...